# C# REPL Entity Framework .edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, read-eval-print-loop

How to load entity framework in C# REPL in VS2015?

I am trying to do it like this:

```
var db = new Container("connectionstring");
db.Contacts.First();
```

I took connection string from web.config of my MVC 5 application which works fine with SQL Server 2014.

```
<add name="myCS" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASSWORD;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

it throws on

```
db.Contacts.First();
```

Error:

> Keyword not supported: 'data source'.
>   + System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(IDictionary, string, IList)

Tried other connection strings, but no luck still.

Tried to point to Model.csdl etc. files by specifying path `obj/Debug/*/*`.

Sample connection string I use is:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASSWORD;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False&quot;"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because of the embedded `&quot;`'s in the connection string?

Comment: Thanks! That was an issue, but I needed to replace &quot; with escaped \" inside string.